# How to keep display aspect ratio and display scaling using wmi?

Tags: display, intel-graphics, wmi

I have Intel HD Graphics 4400 here and I am using the Intel Control tool to set "keep aspect ratio" or "keep display scaling" ("Displayskalierung beibehalten").

Is there a way to achieve this by WMI?